# How to concatenate a php string when we use .val()?

Tags: jquery

I have an input field and I am populating a `<span>` tag with its value but I need to append a php string next to it. At the moment if I use the following it overrides even the php string

Html

```
<input id="nameField" />
<p><span id="userName"></span> + <?php echo $string; ?></p>
```

JQuery

```
$('#nameField').on('keyup', function() {
   var my_value = $(this).val();
   $('span#userName').html(my_value);
});
```

Comment: The posted code doesn't do what you have described.

Comment: It won't work because PHP is processed by the server before the page is sent to the browser.  You are trying to get the browser to process it.  You need an AJAX call

Comment: Maybe use append() rather than val()?

Comment: If your code is as you posted `$('span#userName').html()` will not change html after it

Comment: Ah right.. mmm, i see

Comment: it is changing the html tho

Comment: why on earth did i get a down vote?

Comment: I think its because your code does not describe your problem, your code looks good.

Comment: @Steve the php is outputting the string before the input field interaction and it's fine. What I am trying to do is to add before the string in the html whatever it is written in the input field. SO it's adding text basically, shouldn't remove the whole thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

completely updating my answer :

I've simplified this

```
<span id="userName"></span>
<input type="text" class="typehere">


var input = $('.typehere'),
    output = $('span#userName')
;


input.on('keydown keypress', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        output.text(input.val());
    }, 0);
});
```

that will give you the live typing.

The PHP is rendered on the server side, so as long as that is outside of the span it should be okay,

check out this fiddle.  :  http://jsfiddle.net/pushplaybang/3aEFm/3/

Comment: yeah append doesn't really work as if i press the backspace key to delete a letter the span will add again what's left on the input field

Comment: sure - realised that straight after I posted it - but what about the concatanation? - you will also want to debounce this I would imiagine.

Comment: Yes the concatenation would work maybe, where would you put the php string tho? I am not sure in your code, is it within the " " ?

Comment: have scraped my previous answer - hope this one fits, seems to work from what I understand of your question.  Good Luck

Comment: the markup in the js fiddle I linked to is closer to your original question - btw.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but really I am confused, look at my code in the question, the php is outside the span, so I don't mind if this is generated before by the server, all I want to do is add some text before that once typing. I don't understand why if the php string is outside the span the jQuery is overiding that too

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to append your value to php string.

```
$('#nameField').on('keyup', function() {
   var my_value = $(this).val();
   $('span#userName').append(my_value);
});
```

Comment: Crazy, my answer was within my own question! I had to use append! Ok, i'm tired. Thanks a lot

Comment: actually this doens't work, because each time i have a keyup it adds it, what if i press backspace tho? SHoudl remove the letters

Comment: Actually you didnt mentioned that part in question. Any way update your question.

Comment: actually in the question i do specify that when I use the code provided it overwrides the php, so your answer it is partly correct but it creates a new issue which i didn't have before.

Comment: Above answer will not override php, because your php string is in `p` tag and above code will append data to `span`.

Comment: i haven't said your code does that, I said my code did the overwrriding. However, I did say your code create another issue which is my comment here

Comment: look what happens with your code when we have a keyup http://jsfiddle.net/a8jbF/1/

Comment: Then you should make sure that you are not overriding php string. Post your whole code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and explain what you need exactly that would ne helpful for you to get exact answer bro.

Comment: I am making sure it doesn't overides the php string! it is writing within the span if you take a look at the code. And the php is outside the span.